# Can't boot from SATA dvd, seen as SerialCH1_Master

Tags: boot, bios

Here's the problem: I have an old computer based on an AsRock motherbord, the p4vt8+.
I have 2 IDE HDs , one per each channel (IDE0 and IDE1) and I have a SATA dvd LG GH22N550.
When I go into the BIOS panel on the boot devices list I can see IDE0 and IDE1 but not the dvd that I need to install Windows.

When the computer is booting I can see it under the voice SerialCH1_Master.

I know I'm doing something wrong but I can't figure out what it is.

**UPDATE:** updated my BIOS to the last one available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your SATA needs to have drivers installed from floppy before it can be used. Under normal circumstances the Windows disk would prompt for these drivers but you have the DVD drive connected to the SATA so it is never going to work as it stands.

Your manual is [here](http://europe.asrock.com/manual/P4VT8+.pdf) and the relevant page is #17

> Making an SATA HDD driver diskette...
>   If you want to install Windows 2000 or Windows XP on your system while
>   you only have SATA HDDs on your system, you will need to make an SATA
>   HDD driver diskette before you start the OS installation.

I know it refers to HDDs but the principle is the same. You would have more luck if you can borrow an IDE DVD drive or an external USB one (assuming you can boot from USB)

Comment: I actually did that. I've used an IDE DVD drive. Nonetheless I'll try to install the SATA drivers.

Answer (score 0):

1)First I Recommend you Check the SATA cable that you are using.Replace with an other one.

2)Check if Jumpers are set correctly for IDE0 and IDE1 devices.

If this doesn't solve your problem it could be a simple BIOS update or update SATA Driver for Windows.
You can find update for your MotherBoard here at Official AsRock Site:
[Drivers and BIOS Updates for P4VT8+](http://www.asrock.com/mb/download.asp?Model=P4VT8%2b&o=All#bios)

See if that work.

Comment: Yep, I've checked the official site but I have 2 problems. First thing is that it says I should use a floppy to update my BIOS and I don't have a floppy drive: could I do it using an usb stick? If yes could you point me somewhere(a tutorial)? Second thing is I do not have windows, I have to install it and since I can see the freaking dvd reader, I can't install windows SATA drivers.

Comment: I've actually managed the thing. I've installed the BIOS update. Now it's 1.60 (2005) but still no SATA. Could you be more specific about the jumpers? They're on 2 separate IDE Channel so they're both master.